# use tkinter for nltk draw inside of jupyter notebook

Tags: python, docker, tkinter, nltk, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to draw graph (**inline**) of `nltk` inside of `jupyter-notebook`. But got error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

I have tried to set `$DISPLAY` to different values:

```
$env DISPLAY=0.0
# or
$env DISPLAY=inline
# or
$env DISPLAY=
```

but got error (or similar):

```
TclError: couldn't connect to display "0.0"
```

here is my code https://github.com/hyzhak/nltk-experiments/blob/master/main.ipynb the last cell.

Environment: official anaconda3 docker -- `continuumio/anaconda3:4.4.0` https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images. With `nltk==3.2.3` inside.

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

How could I solve this error and **inline** `nltk` graph inside of `jupyter notebook`?

## Update 1

http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/tree.html#draw_trees according to the sources of nltk tree draw it uses `tkinter`.

## Update 2

I have asked the same question in official nltk github repository https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1765

## Update 3

I think the reason of error could be the headless host (docker). I have installed `xvfb` but seems it is note enough.

```
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
```

## Solution

I thought that `xvfb` is launched by default but It should be run explicitly. So after I have launched it I could make screenshots of nltk tree graph.

Comment: Hey, how do you run `xvfb` explicitly? I ran the `Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16` command but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: I have launched it as a daemon.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
import nltk
from IPython.display import Image

chunkGram = r"""Chunk: {<RB.?>*<VB.?>*<NNP>+<NN>?}"""
chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)

tagged = [('Tonight', 'NN'), ('we', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('comforted', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('hope', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('a', 'DT'), ('glad', 'JJ'), ('reunion', 'NN'), ('with', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('husband', 'NN'), ('who', 'WP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('taken', 'VBN'), ('so', 'RB'), ('long', 'RB'), ('ago', 'RB'), (',', ','), ('and', 'CC'), ('we', 'PRP'), ('are', 'VBP'), ('grateful', 'JJ'), ('for', 'IN'), ('the', 'DT'), ('good', 'JJ'), ('life', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), ('Coretta', 'NNP'), ('Scott', 'NNP'), ('King', 'NNP'), ('.', '.')]
chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged)
nltk.draw.tree.TreeView(chunked)._cframe.print_to_file('output.ps')
os.system('convert output.ps output.png')

Image(filename='output.png')
```

[out]:

[image]

Comment: the same error because `nltk.draw.tree.TreeView` create `tkinter` instance `self._top = Tk()` (http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/tree.html#TreeView)

Comment: ok, interesting, did you run jupyter on your local host system or inside of docker or remote host? Could it be the problem of Anaconda docker?

Comment: I would think it is the conda docker. I ran jupyter on local.

Comment: Can you print any image on jupyter notebook inside the docker? If so, simply saving to post-script -> png and displaying an image would work. Otherwise, it's a bug downstream on conda docker's side

Comment: Nonono, not matplotlib, just simple image printing onto Jupyter console =). I.e. Does this work? `from IPython.display import Image; Image(filename='output.png') `.

Comment: yes, it works as well. I think problem with virtual display itself. I have `x11vnc` and `xvfb` to have virtual display there (docker doesn't have display it is completely virtual environment) but seems it is not enough.

Comment: ok, it was problem with `xvfb` I have forgot to launch it. Latter

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating the following snippet in your code

```
import os
import matplotlib as mpl
if os.environ.get('DISPLAY','') == '':
    print('no display found. Using non-interactive Agg backend')
    mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Regardless. Your problem is that Matplotlib's default call to an x-using backend is apparently causing a problem. This answer is by no means the only possible solution, but I think this will solve your problem.
Remember that it is important to switch backend **before** importing pyplot.

Alternatively, you could try 
IPython.core.display.display(chunked)

Make sure that your notebook server is started with the -X flag set..

```
def jupyter_draw_nltk_tree(tree):
    from IPython.display import Image, display
    from nltk.draw import TreeWidget
    from nltk.draw.util import CanvasFrame
    import subprocess
    cf = CanvasFrame()
    tc = TreeWidget(cf.canvas(), tree)
    tc['node_font'] = 'arial 13 bold'
    tc['leaf_font'] = 'arial 14'
    tc['node_color'] = '#005990'
    tc['leaf_color'] = '#3F8F57'
    tc['line_color'] = '#175252'
    cf.add_widget(tc, 10, 10)
    cf.print_to_file('tmp_tree_output.ps')
    cf.destroy()

    args = (['convert', 'tmp_tree_output.ps', 'tmp_tree_output.png'])
    subprocess.call(args)
    display(Image(filename='tmp_tree_output.png'))
    os.system('rm tmp_tree_output.ps tmp_tree_output.png')

jupyter_draw_nltk_tree(chunked)
```

Comment: I've got the same error. As I understand `nltk` uses `tkinter` direct, and ignore `matplotlib`. Maybe there other way to draw graph of `nltk` without using inner (nltk) graph method?

Comment: http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/draw/tree.html#draw_trees I've just taken a look in the sources of graph draw and found that really it doesn't use matplotlib for drawing graph. Very strange :(

Comment: second solution doesn't work as well because `CanvasFrame()` tries to create tkinter widget. Did you draw nltk tree graph inside of jupyter notebook?