# How to draw nltk tree on headless jupyter notebook server [have tried a bunch of "solutions" but none worked]

Tags: tkinter, jupyter-notebook, nltk

With a simple example with `nltk.tree` running on a jupyter-notebook on a remote server:

```
import nltk
parser = nltk.RegexpParser(r'NP: {<[NJ].*>+}')
tree = parser.parse(nltk.corpus.brown.tagged_sents()[0])
tree
```

will give you the error `TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable`. I have tried a bunch of solutions to this, e.g., `Agg` backend, `ssh -Y`, [`Ipython display`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880337/use-tkinter-for-nltk-draw-inside-of-jupyter-notebook), [`%matplotlib inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779707/how-do-you-make-nltk-draw-trees-that-are-inline-in-ipython-jupyter), but none seems working. Are there any solutions to this issue as of today?